# Can we interpret the scalar multiplication in a vector space as a group action of the field onto the set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, group-actions

Any vector space V over a field F by definition contains in it a rule or a operation called scalar multiplication which associates with each scalar 'c' in F, a vector 'c$.\alpha$' in V such that,

i) 1.$\alpha$ = $\alpha$

ii)($c_1*c_2).\alpha$ = $c_1.(c_2.\alpha)$

are satisfied where 1 is the multiplicative identity of the field of scalars F.

So, there must be some natural interpretation of why we define a vector space in a way that the field of scalars if considered as a group with multiplication '*' (ignoring the addition operation since here, $(c_1+c_2).\alpha \neq c_1.(c_2.\alpha)$) acts on the so called set of vectors V. Here the set V before the group action can also be considered as a commutative group with the addition operation.

Does this mean that the orbits corresponding to this group action on V is nothing but all the possible one dimensional subspaces of V? (Example: If V is the coordinate plane and the scalar field is the set of real numbers, then the orbits of V are all the lines passing through the origin?)

Lastly, then what would be the relevance of these remaining rules:

iii)$c.(\alpha+\beta) = c.\alpha+c.\beta$

iv)$(c_1+c_2).\alpha = c_1.\alpha+c_2.\alpha$

Comment: It is not a *group* action on a set but a *ring* action on an abelian group. A group action $G \times X \to X$ of a group $G$ on a set $X$ has the same information as a group homomorphism $G \to {\rm Perm}(X)$ from $G$ to the group of all permutations of $X$, while the scalar multiplication $F \times V \to V$ where $(c,v) \mapsto cv$ has the same information as a ring homomorphism $F \to {\rm Hom}(V,V)$ from $F$ to the ring of homomorphisms from $V$ to itself.  You can replace $F$ with a commutative ring $R$ and this becomes an $R$-module instead of an $F$-vector space.

Comment: That's very close to what I was looking for. Thank you for introducing me to ring actions and modules!

Comment: @BenjaminKurian Is $\text{Perm}(X)$ somehow analogous to $\text{Hom}(V,V)$, then?

Comment: Is there a place where scalar multiplication is studied as a ring homomorphism $F \longmapsto \text{Hom}(V,V)$ more in depth?